# Image not shown properly on 000webhost server

Tags: html, css

I am making this page http://pagota.herobo.com with the JavaScript library called curtain JS. When you scroll down the page on `#section4` where it says delivery& prices you can't see the picture proberly but the content of section 5.

The site I have it hosted on `000webhost`. The problem only happens on their server and not locally on my machine.

Anyone could help me on this. The CSS I am using for displaying the pic is background:`url(../img/prices.png)50% 0 no-repeat, url(../img/bg.png)50% 0 repeat`;

The first picture(`prices.png`) has a transparent background and the second one is a pic with background of a grey color.

Comment: Can you add the web directoty, please? (in the host)

Comment: you can view the source of the page by right clicking on the page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you go to http://pagota.herobo.com/img/, you can see that your file is not called `bg.png`, but rather `bg.PNG`.
I suppose you're working on Windows. Windows file names are case-insensitive. That's why the image is showing on your machine, but not on the server. Either change the filename to `bg.png` or change the name in the CSS to `bg.PNG` and it should work.

Comment: My pleasure! if this was the answer you're looking for, it would be nice to accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left (you should always accept an answer if it answered your question).